# VBA Rows.Count and UsedRange returning "1"

Tags: vba

I have a small macro which takes data from multiple xml files and pastes in xlsm. Each xml file has a tag name, and the column the data pastes into has the tag name in row 4. I'm trying to paste into one below the last used row, but the three methods I have below keep returning "1" for the last used row. 
Asterisks is the code I'm having trouble with.

```
For Z = 1 To 16

        If Cells(4, Z).Value Like i Then
            Dim Lengthend As Double
            Dim An As Variant
            An = (Split(Cells(4, Z).Address(True, False), "$")(0))
Lengthend = *****
            Cells(Lengthend + 1, Z).Select
            Cells(Lengthend + 1, Z).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
```

Here are the three methods I used to find the end of the column:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("PI Data")
sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "An").End(xlUp).Row
```

And

```
Lengthend = Range("An" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

And

```
(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(An).Count)
```

Each of these methods returns the answer "1." Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: change `Dim Lengthend As Double` to `Dim Lengthend As Long`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Lengthend = Range("An" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The above has a typo and works if you change it to - what you propably tried to do is pass the value of variable An and not value "An"

```
Lengthend = Range(An & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

You should also define the worksheet you are referring to to avoid any further problems -

```
Lengthend = Sheets("PI Data").Range(An & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```